# Google Chrome download file with used CSS only

Tags: css, google-chrome, audit

Is it somehow possible to download a file with used CSS only after performing a page audit in Google Chrome? I'm using Bootstrap CSS and there's a lot stuff which is not used actually.

The page audit shows me which CSS are used and which are not - but feature is pretty useless when dealing with a file with more than 10.000 rows if I can't download it somehow. So is there some convenient solution for that problem?

Answer (score -1):

> if I can't download it somehow

You can't or don't want to? Are you talking about the CSS file itself?

There is no way not to download parts of a big CSS file.But if you already know that some of them are unused then delete them from pack. Or if you are not sure, you could determine it on server side - if you have any back-end code. Or maybe you could check it by using client side JS - for example by checking used CSS classes. But in my opinion it could be bigger overhead than downloading unnecessary CSS files.